# Using a communication layer for communication between a Client and a Server

Tags: java

Here is my issue in more detail than my previous post.

I'm following a spec, which says I have to write a Comms class for communication between the Client and the Server:

> Write a Comms class that will handle communication between the server application and the client applications. Provide a 'sendMessage' method that allows each client to send a message object to the Server and the Server to send a message to a specific client. The applications will also need to check for incoming messages by calling a 'receiveMessage' method (or methods) of the Comms class. The types of these may vary depending on the types of message being sent/received.
>
> For the purposes of this assignment, you may assume that the server and client applications run on the same machine (but in separate JVMs) [...].
>
> [...] all I/O operations must reside in the Comms class. Access to them is only allowed via your send/receive methods above.

My current Comms class is as follows: https://ghostbin.com/paste/jnar2

The Server class is fairly large but I've only included the constructor and an example method within it which would have to be called by the Client as well as some of the data structures it uses: https://ghostbin.com/paste/tsqhc

Finally, the Client class doesn't have much of note within it, maybe except for its constructor: https://ghostbin.com/paste/cvdvx

I don't know where to begin -- I'd imagine I'm meant to be calling Server's methods from within Client, somehow using the Comms class as a layer between the two. But I don't know how I'd go about that

Comment: How do you plan on getting the two bits of code to communicate?  You may want to look into Sockets, unless you have another plan

Comment: @phflack yes I plan on using sockets, you can see that I've started to use them in the Comm class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough template of what I think the Comm class should look like. Note: Here I am working with "pure" strings and not Message Objects. For objects you could use ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream wrapped around the socket instead.

```
public class Comm {
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Comm(Socket sock) throws IOException {
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush()
    }

    //This is blocking until line is received from socket.
    public String recieveMessage() {
        return in.readLine();
    }
}
```

Key idea of this implementation is that there are no server-only or client-only components in the Comm class such that both client/server could use this class. On the client side you would initiate the socket through address/port and on server side through a ServerSocket listening.

Client side:

```
public class Client {

    private Comm clientIO;
    private Socket sock;

    public Client(String addr, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        sock = new Socket(addr, port);
        clientIO = new Comm(sock);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Client c = new Client("localhost", 15000);
        c.clientIO.sendMessage("getDishes()");
        String returned = c.clientIO.recieveMessage();
        System.out.println(returned);
        c.sock.close();
    }

}
```

Server side:

```
public class Server {

    private Comm serverIO;
    private ServerSocket serverSock;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {   
        Server s = new Server(15000);
        Socket sock = s.serverSock.accept();
        s.serverIO = new Comm(sock);
        String command = s.serverIO.recieveMessage();
        if (command.equals("getDishes()")) {
            s.serverIO.sendMessage("Correct command");
        } else {
            s.serverIO.sendMessage("Unknown command");
        }
        sock.close();
        s.serverSock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For `sendMessage(String message)`, how would I use this to call a method in `Server`?

Comment: @seneca On receiving a message, read it and decide which method to call?

Comment: Yes you could use this in any way. On a server I would create a list of accepted socket connections and initiate one thread per connection. You did not specify what to do with the input so its hard for me to give further explanation.

Comment: What I mean is that for example in `Client` I want to call a method, for example the `getDishes()` method that's in my code in the attached link. I'm thinking I'm meant to do something similar to this:


1. Client calls `sendMessage()` with a string `getDishes`

2. This is received in `Server` (inside the `getDishes()` method) and it then calls the method there

Comment: @Jonaswg thank you, this is making sense now! I have another question though: I don't only want to deal with Strings. For instance, while `recieveMessage()` returning a String is fine for a method like `getRestaurantName()`, it isn't for the actual `getDishes()` method because that returns a `List<Dish>`. How do I handle different types of Object?

Comment: Serialization. Personally I just use Googles GSON API to "stringify" objects into JSON strings and send them as such through the socket. Alternative is to use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream